# Why does IStringLocalizer dependency injection throw an error when executing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm really new to .net core programming and I came across this issue which I can't wrap my head around. The solution builds fine and the homepage comes up, but when I do any action, like try to login I get this error: (AcademiejaarInst is a domain class)

```
InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor found for entity type 'AcademiejaarInst'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'localizer' in 'AcademiejaarInst(IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> localizer)'.
```

ctor of AcademiejaarInst

```
public class AcademiejaarInst
{

    private static IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> _localizer;
    public AcademiejaarInst(IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }
...
```

This also is the case if I try to do the migrations. Obviously something's not right with the Localization Injection but I don't know why. These are the relevant LoCs in StartUp.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      ...
      services.AddMvc(config => ... )
     .AddViewLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
     .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => {
                    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                        factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
                });

     // I tried this but was absolutely not sure this would work.
     services.AddTransient<AcademiejaarInst>();
     services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizer, StringLocalizer<SharedResource>>();
     services.AddLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

     services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
     {
         var supportedCultures = new[]
         {
                    new CultureInfo("nl-BE")
         };
         options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("nl-BE", "nl_BE");

         options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;

                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
     });
     ...
   }
```

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The `services.AddLocalization()` call already wires up appropriate implementations for the interface `IStringLocalizer<T>`, so you don't actually need to inject it yourself, which I reckon is where your issues come from.

Removing the line where you inject a specific implementation for the `IStringLocalizer` interface should solve your problem.

Comment: services.AddLocalization() works for me (y)

Answer (score -2):

In the AcademiejaarInst constructor you are expecting a `IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>`, but there is no configuration for this type.

If you change

```
services.AddSingleton<IStringLocalizer, StringLocalizer<SharedResource>>();
```

to

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IStringLocalizer<SharedResource>), typeof(StringLocalizer<SharedResource));
```

it should work

Comment: Thank you for your input, and I tried it but i still get the same error...